# Global htmlentities ENT_COMPAT setup

Tags: php, html-entities

When moving from PHP 5.3 to 5.4, there is a change on `htmlentities()` function behavior. Accented words disappear when using echo `htmlentities($var);`.
It is necessary to use `echo htmlentities($var,ENT_COMPAT,"ISO-8859-1");`.

Is there an option to set a global parameter for every time `htmlentities` is called to use `ENT_COMPAT "ISO-8859-1"`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create function for this

```
function escape($var)
{
 return htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1"));
}
```

Comment: Its an application that is being moved from a php 5.3 server to a php 5.4 server. I would prefer to leave the code untouched, if there is a solution that can change the htmlentities() behaviour on a global mode.